# Cutoff functions in the proof of $H^2$ inner regularity of the elliptic equations

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, elliptic-equations

Here is the $H^2$ regularity theorem for the elliptic equations in Evans's *Partial Differential Equations (2nd edition)*:

> [image]
>   Here $U\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is assumed to be open and bounded.

The first big step of the proof gives the following:

> [image]

All that is left to do for the proof is "replacing" the $H^1(U)$ norm with $L^2(U)$ norm in $(23)$, which one can easily see by comparing (23) with (8). Instead of directly dealing with $\|u\|_{H^1(U)}$, Evans takes one step back and makes the following argument:

> [image]
>   Here (9) is given by
>   [image]

I can follow each step in this part logically, but I don't see the point of using of $W$ (and the cutoff function) here.

Evans makes a point at the beginning of the proof:

> [image]

Here are my **questions**:

- Would anyone explicitly point out why $W$ is needed in the argument above?
- What would/could be wrong if one erases the cutoff function $\zeta$
  and replaces $W$ with $U$ (so that we can use (23) directly) in the
  red box?
- [Added in light of mcd's answer:] If one does need the cutoff function $\zeta$, then can he use $v=\zeta u$ instead of $v=\zeta^2 u$?

Comment: Actually it is very important to use $v=\zeta^2 u$ and not the naive choice of $v=\zeta u$. This is a rather technical, though very important, point, and the same trick shows up very often in PDE. There is not an easy explanation of this beyond trying the proof with $v=\zeta u$ and seeing where it fails.

Comment: @Jeff: Thanks for pointing that out. Having gone through the proof for $v=\zeta u$ to see why it fails (since I don't know why one needs the cutoff function $\zeta$ in the first place, i.e. how the proof fails with $v=u$), I guess the reason for $v=\zeta^2u$ is similar to the need of $\zeta$ itself?  When one takes the *derivative* of $v=\zeta^2 u$, by product rule, $\partial_iv=\color{blue}{2\zeta(\partial_i \zeta) u}+\partial_i u\zeta^2$. One might need the $\zeta$ as well for the first term on the right hand side.

Comment: Yes, the reason is you want a term $\zeta$ to show up on the right after differentiating. Then when you use Cauchy's inequality with $\epsilon$ you get terms with $\zeta^2$ on the right hand side that can be absorbed into the left hand side to get the estimate.

Comment: @mcd gave a good answer as to why the cutoff is required. Evans places no boundary conditions on $u$ in this theorem, so the notion of weak solution requires using test functions $v \in H^1_0(U)$, so the integration by parts step is valid. So you want to use $v=u$ as a test function, but this is not allowed because $u \not\in H^1_0(U)$. So the natural thing to try is to cutoff $u$ near the boundary so that it is compactly supported. You would try $v=\zeta u$ first, and after plugging away for a while you get stuck and realize that $v=\zeta^2 u$ works better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you transform the problem into its weak formulation you need to apply integration by parts several times. For this you need that your test function $v$ to vanish at the boundary $\partial U$. Evans does impose any condition on $u$ on the boundary, so $u \not \in H^1_0$. He has to use a cut-off so that $B[u,\zeta^2 u] = (f, \zeta^2 u)$ holds. This he uses to deduce the first equation in your red box.

I did not see it immediately, but i strongly suspect that at one point you need that $\partial_{x_j} v = 0$ on the boundary. If you did impose these conditions on $u$ then the problem would no longer be well-defined as you have to many boundary conditions.